# Recyclerview - Getting the position from button in viewholder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i want to get the position from the row, where my button is when i click it.

Its in a viewholder, and has a on click event. 
When i use `getPosition();`, i become every time, at each click, at different rows -1. 
I found out, that in the "row" click listener, i can get the right position, but i dont know how i can transfer that value, to the button click.

My code looks currently like this:

```
        debug("position0: "+pos);

        done_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                debug("position1: " + pos);

                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);

                Snackbar
                        .make(v.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar), "Notice marked as done", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E91E63"))
                        .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                debug("position2: "+pos);
                                adapter.notifyItemInserted(pos);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();

            }
        });
```

Are there any suggestions? Let me know :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are never using `getPosition()` anywhere in the code you posted but anyway you should be using `getAdapterPosition()` instead.

Comment: lol, `getAdapterPosition()` work fine now ^^ i just tried both, but it didnt work :o But how i have to use the, `notifyItemInserted(pos)` and `notifyItemRemoved(pos)`? Currently everytime the last item, get removed and inserted again,  :/ the same which button from which row i click

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can use this in button 

//first create custom button by extending and add this line 

public int butposition (){

    //to use this make sure ure button is direct child of the recyclerview else u 
    //have to call child at again 

    int iPosition = -1;
        if (this.getParent() instanceof RecyclerView)
            iPosition = ((RecyclerView) 
    getParent()).getChildAdapterPosition(this);
```